# How to integrate Spine animations to a SpriteKit game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, spine

I need to integrate animations to an iOS SpriteKit game. The artist provides them in [Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com/) format. Such animation consists of a set of images, a .spine file describing the animations and a .json file describing the metadata.

I see two possible ways to solve this problem:

1. Find (or make) a module allowing to add nodes and related animations from Spine files to a SpriteKit scene.
2. Convert the animation to a different format which can be imported to SpriteKit easily.

Please, share your experience. Any help is welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library that allows you to do exactly that. Installing & usage examples are in the description of the library.

https://github.com/maxgribov/Spine

Comment: May be you can share your experience using this library with SpriteKit?

Comment: Ok, I tested different frameworks like simonkim/spine-spritekit, nikki2pro/YSC_SpineSwiftTest, mredig/SGG_SKSpineImport. They are outdated, don't support latest Swift even. Although maxgribov/Spine has lots of issues it's the best one.